# in a F# class, how can I use a value in another value at initialization time?

Tags: constructor, f#

I'm trying to replicate C# code that has three dictionaries:

```
Dictionary<string, float> DictionaryA = new Dictionary<string, float>();
Dictionary<string, float> DictionaryB = new Dictionary<string, float>();
Dictionary<MyEnum, Dictionary<string, float>> Dictionaries
    = new Dictionary<MyEnum, Dictionary<string, float>>();
```

and, in the constructor:

```
Dictionaries[MyEnum.A] = DictionaryA
Dictionaries[MyEnum.B] = DictionaryB
```

so, in F#, I do this:

```
member val private DictionaryA = new Dictionary<string, float>()
member val private DictionaryB = new Dictionary<string, float>()
```

but then, in the constructor, it looks like 'this' is not available:

```
do
    this.Dictionaries.Add(MyEnum.A, this.DictionaryA) |> ignore
    this.Dictionaries.Add(MyEnum.B, this.DictionaryB) |> ignore
```

will not work.

how can I initialize that third dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you won't mutate the fields itself after constructing the object, so

```
open System.Collections.Generic

type Foo() =
    let a = new Dictionary<string, float>()
    let b = new Dictionary<string, float>()
    let t = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, float>>()
    do
        t.Add(1, a)
        t.Add(2, b)
```